# Check if input field is empty or not

Tags: codeigniter, validation, input

I have 10 textboxes x 3 so about 30.

Name - Age - SEx

so 10 persons in all.

I have this current code:

```
if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST)){  //CHECKS IF FORM WAS SUBMITTED, ELSE LOADS TO VIEW

for($counter=1;$counter<11;$counter++){ //I LOOPED THE 10 FIELDS, STARTING FROM 1, 1-10
if($_POST['ingredient'.$counter]!=null){ // CHECK IF ATLEAST NAME IS NOT EMPTY, IF EMPTY EVEN IF THE OTHER 2 INPUTS ARE NOT I WILL NOT INCLUDE IT.

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('Name'.$counter,'Name #'.$counter,'trim');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('Age'.$counter,'Age of'.$_POST['name'.$counter],'trim|required|numeric');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('Sex'.$counter,'Gender of'.$_POST['name'.$counter],'trim|required');
          }
```

Im only adding required on the other 2 fields since name shouldnt be null to be inside the `if(success){  }` clause

Is there any other better way?

CALLBACK QUESTIONS.

When using form_validation, say i used a callback function. how would i be able to print the necessary error_message for that callback since ci wont be able to know what that function was all about.

Comment: do you know you can use something like `name="age[]"` an array structure for age data, then you can use a callback function

Comment: I use that for deleting rows where in i store in the values='<?=$id?>'